# Counting occurrences in a column

Tags: sas

I have a dataset with >7K observations.  I have a column RFLP that can have a numerous amount of different responses.  I want to get a table that tells me how many occurrences of each unique response are in the column.  Since there are so many responses, I am not able to specify them in the statement.

Thanks!
Denise

Comment: What is your SAS background?  This sounds like PROC FREQ to me, which is basically day 1 SAS, so I'm curious if you're not explaining something sufficiently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use `proc sql`.  This is an aggregation query:

```
proc sql;
    select rflp, count(*)
    from <dataset>
    group by rflp;
```